# Expose a view's filters both in a block, and in the actual view

Tags: views

I made a View, and I exposed the filters in a block; then, in the block's administrative screen, I set this block not to appear in the view that belong. In the actual view I don't want to show this block. Instead, I want the filters to appear in the content as they normally would if I didn't expose them in a block.

If that makes any difference, I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that your view has exposed filters and that *Exposed form in block* is set to Yes.

To put the exposed form where it would appear if it weren't in block, you should be able to place the exposed form block into your *Content* region, above the view itself.

To have the exposed form displayed in both the view and a separate block, leave the form in the view and create a PHP block with the following body:

```
<?php
  if ($block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', '-exp-YOUR_VIEW-YOUR_DISPLAY') ) {
    print $block['content'] ;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer did not work with Drupal 7 for me. 
I followed http://www.drup-all.com/blog/exposed-filters-form-your-custom-block-drupal-7 with success. Code below:

```
/** implements hook_block_info() **/
function test_block_info(){
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['custom_exposed_filter_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Exposed filter form'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/** implements hook_block_view() **/
function test_block_view($delta = ''){
  $block = array();
  switch($delta){
    case 'custom_exposed_filter_form':
      $block['subject'] = t('Exposed filter form');
      $block['content'] = _test_get_exposed_filter_form();   
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/** Function to get the Exposed filter form **/
function _test_get_exposed_filter_form(){
  // Get a view from the database or from default views . "test" is the view name.
  $view = views_get_view('test');
  // Set the display as current.
  $view->set_display('page');
  // Acquire and attach all of the handlers to the view.
  $view->init_handlers();
  $exposed_form = $view->display_handler->get_plugin('exposed_form');
  return $exposed_form->render_exposed_form();
}
```

Comment: Though a great solution, be aware of issues when loading a block like this on a Panelized page. See https://www.drupal.org/node/26365523.

Answer (score 1):

```
$block = block_load('views', '-exp-VIEW_NAME-VIEW_DISPLAY');
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
echo($output);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little summary of why/how this is different that the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Views UI alternative to the accepted answer, at least with Views 3 / D7:

- configure your view with the view exposed form *you'd like to see on the view page*
- **Clone that view** and for sake of future remembering, call it search block
- In the search block view, in advanced setup, set **Show the exposed form in a block : Yes**
- It 's important that **both views have the same path**
- Display the block where ever you'd like to

It's worth saying that with this method you **can now edit the search block** and remove some filters, add markup... (but no filters that would not be in the mother view I believe).

You can even reproduce steps and have **different custom blocks pointing to the same view.**

I've done that recently and found it very useful