# How to make exposed filter show results on another page?

Tags: blocks, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expose Views filters both in a block but in the actual view also](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/expose-views-filters-both-in-a-block-but-in-the-actual-view-also)

I have a Views-based page (Page A) with exposed autocomplete filter. I want that filter form to appear in a block on Page B, but the search results should be displayed on Page A.

Unfortunately I have to search open value fields (node title), which eliminates Better Exposed Filters from play.

Does anyone know of a ready module that could work for me?

Comment: [The answer was hanging out around](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/expose-views-filters-both-in-a-block-but-in-the-actual-view-also).

Answer (score 2):

In Advanced section :
EXPOSED FORM
Exposed form in block:No -> set it to yes

Comment: Thanks. And is it the way it works, that it takes away the exposed form from the page? I would like it to appear both in block and on the target page.

Comment: It will appear as a block , and in the block visibility settings you will have to specify the path of your two pages

Comment: Yes, I understand, but both instances will appear in same region, won't they? My goal (with which I haven't been clear in my question) is to have the exposed filter shown in the traditional way on a view page, above the content (ie. content region), and I want its copy to appear as block in the right sidebar, if not also in OM Maximenu. I think I'll have to look at render_exposed_form() quoted here http://drupal.org/node/757470.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite this is what you are looking for, but, check out this page:

http://timeline.med.utoronto.ca/page/historical-or-individual-artifacts

If you want that to happen (filters are exposed), results shown in block in the content section, you simply have to turn on Ajax in your View Advanced settings. If it is off, the View will load the results on a separate page.